# Assign limited available core of cpu for queue in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, queue, cpu

First, I go around on Google but nothing like what I want, so I think it's better if I put question here.

My case is I'd like to implement a queue in our web application, but for performance of website, I don't want the queue can take a lot of cpus so I want to limit core of cpu for queue. So when queue is run together with web, website is not too slow.

Example: our cpu has 4 cores 8 threads. We can assign 2 core or 4 threads for queue, so website can run smoothly with the rest.

I researched with some kind of queues (MSMQ, SQS, ..) but they are not handle the core or thread of CPU.

Anyone has any idea on it ?

Regards,
Good luck for all

Comment: Is the fundamental work here single-threaded? if so, writing an in-memory synchronized queue with some number N of threads as workers (dequeing work items, using appropriate wait primitives) is about 20 minutes work... then just add stuff to the queue and let the workers worry about it. Additionally, you might benefit from separating your web-tier from your workers - obviously then you need a backing queue store, but again: firing up N threads who are dequeing work: not usually a tricky problem to solve.

Comment: You mention a website, so I assume ASP.NET. If that is the case then I suggest you check out this very useful article: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx